# Making repeated Texts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to search in the database. When I search the database I must display results in the form.
I want to display as google displays the search results.

Link
Description

Link
Description

---

I must do it in the WPF. How can I solve thıs problem?

Comment: I used Listbox for this purpose. But the way I used is not for some reasons. That is why I asked from you about it.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend using an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/). The default `ItemsControl` displays a vertical `StackPanel` containing a `TextBlock` for each item in a Collection. You can overwrite the default templates of an `ItemsControl` to display however you want.

Here's an example that edits the default `ItemTemplate` to display as two TextBlocks instead of a single one:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Link}" Style="{StaticResource LinkTextStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Giving code like that to someone who appears to be completely clueless is unlikely to help, even if he/she knows about bindings there is no real point in providing concrete code, it may just lead to mindless copy-pasting, as i see it (- like with the recent circle question -) one should not *give a man a fish*.

Comment: @HB If I were looking on SO for the answer to a question, I would rather see an explanation with with sample code an than a single line answer containing links that I have to go research. SO is for answers, not for obtaining links to research. The code I posted will not work out of the box, and will require some further research to figure out how to get it working correctly. It provides enough keywords for someone to Google effectively to find what they want.

Comment: +1. This is a simple solution that answers the question directly, and neatly explains the process. HB, downvoting because the answer works but the user doesn't deserve it is ridiculous. SO answers are supposed to work for anyone looking for an answer.

Comment: I agree with Rachel i think her answer is perfectly valid. It gives enough information about how to solve the problem, without a complete From-Zero Introduction to WPF or beeing to shallow.

Comment: I agree with H.B. on the point that this is a standard procedure throughout WPF.  If one does not learn how to choose a particular control, bind, and create a template based on their data; then they will get nowhere.

Comment: @Tyrsius: I never said that that the user does not deserve it, the point was that such answers might do more harm than good, because people may get around even learning the basics leading them to have even more trouble down the road resulting in more basic answers which also seem to be encouraged since apparently people will readily write their code for them, even if it is stuff they really should know themselves.

Comment: @Rachel: It's not like my answer is not an answer, it's just one that is more generic, and if someone does not understand a concept one of the best reasources to understanding said concept is right there. People who google around to get a problem fixed may miss important aspects which they would have gotten if they had invested the time to read the general reference. There are people who have been using bindings for a very long time without even knowing e.g. that it is a MarkupExtensions or how the different sources work.

Comment: @Rachel: I retracted my downvote but i still stand by my view that any solution that can be obtained just by reading the general references on MSDN should warrant an answer without example code.

Comment: @HB Thanks. If that's the case, then downvote the question and vote to close it. Don't downvote answers just because you don't think the question deserves an answer. I get irritated by some of the dumb questions on here too, but usually I just vote to close them. Everyone has to start somewhere, and I don't mind writing answers that point people in the right direction.

Comment: @HB I think that a very specific philosophical position that is probably at odds with the community. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/when-should-correct-answers-get-downvoted for a popular position against yours.

Comment: upvoted this, it is a good answer. Even a poor question like this one can be made useful to someone with good answers like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Create an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx), create a respective [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx).